# Strange behaviour with a service angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angular-services

Here you can find some services used for the sidenav in angular material:

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdSidenav

What i'm using is this one:

```
// Async close the given sidenav
$mdSidenav(componentId)
   .close()
   .then(function(){
     $log.debug('closed');
   });
```

i've just include this in a function in this way:

```
$scope.closeNavDrawer = function () {
            $mdSidenav('versionNav')
                .close()
                .then(function () {
                   $scope.myFunction();
                });
        };
```

so i can call `closeNavDrawer()` in my html view to close the nav. It's working. And when i click the button to close it starts  `$scope.myFunction();` correctly. The strange behaviour is because if i call `closeNavDrawer()` for example after an http get request, it close the nav but the function not starts.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
   $scope.closeNavDrawer(); // it close the nav but not starts $scope.myFunction();
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
  });
```

How is possible this different behaviour?

Comment: I'm assuming there are no JS errors being thrown?  And have you tried to add an error block to the `.close().then()` ?  It could be for some reason its throwing an error and you are silently ignoring it.  If you could re-create in a  fiddle/plunkr we can def help you.

Comment: Well there are no errors. And this is strange..simply it ignore the function. But only if i call the $scope.closeNavDrawer() function from javascript. This is very weird

Comment: In `closeNavDrawer`, what is `$mdSidenav('mySidenav').isOpen() == false` returning. Is it trying to reference a variable called `$scope.isClosed`? If so, I don't expect it to find it, since you called it `$scope.isCLosed`, with a capital 'L'. It'll be `undefined`, which will probably cause issues.

Comment: see my edit, i was wrong with the code. This is the corrected version